# Return country_code from pycountry

Tags: python, django

I have two fields in my usermodel:

```
country = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
code = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
```

I want the second to automatically change once I enter my country, I know how to do it in python shell, but how do I do that in django?

What im trying to do it to print the two digit code in a template.

EDIT: I did this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
...
country = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
code = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)

def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    name=country
    self.code = pycountry.countries.get(name).alpha2
    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The pycountry code is ok, that's the way I get the code in python shell, but 
when I change the country in the admin page the code is throwing

```
global name 'country' is not defined
```

Comment: When exactly does the change need to happen? Just when you save the model?

Comment: Yes, im trying to do so to print it in my template

Comment: alright, check out my answer. You just need to overwrite the model's save method and insert your own logic to assign a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See django docs on models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/

You'd want something like this:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):

    country = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if self.country == foo: #this can be any logic you use to assign the code value
            self.code = a_value
        else:
            self.code = another_value
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This should be just about what you're looking for. Let me know if you find any problems, hope it helps!

Comment: hm, without running it myself I'd say try switching `name=country` to `name=self.country`

Comment: Done. May python gods be with you my friend.